# Python Relative path

Tags: python

I'm having some weird issues regarding relative path. I have a backup framework that works well. And after some update (merely adding py classes but not on that level) my relative path is not working. Already checked my back up data still works. Comparing both framework and it shows it doesn't have any changes on codes. here is my code:

The error:

os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver_v78.0.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

```
def Open_chrome_browser(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("..\\drivers\\chromedriver_v78.0.exe")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WHXO.png)

The one having a problem is here:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXodS.png)

No changes in code. The first image works.  Second wont.

Is there a needed config?

Edited:

Drivers are updated. No changes in path

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfURk.png)

Dont know if this will help but the one in green circle is working when i put this code:
        sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(**file**))

but the yellow is not working

Comment: if you run code from different folder then path is relative to different folder. Use `print(os.getcwd())` to see which folder is use as CWD (Current Working Directory) when you run code. You can also test absolute path - `print( os.path.abspath('..\\drivers\\chromedriver_v78.0.exe') )`. And when you get absolute path then check if it exists on disk and if there is `.exe` file. And if it works correctly - maybe it is broken.

Comment: based on this code the abspath. i got this which is correct. C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\Payroll Framework\Sprout_Payroll_Framework\src\Test\drivers\chromedriver_v78.0.exe

although not sure why it wont work :\

Comment: did you test it in `Open_chrome_browser` ?

Comment: yes the error produce : 'chromedriver_v78.0.exe' executable needs to be in PATH.

Comment: always put FULL error message (not only last line) in question (not in comment)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current file path by using of the following codes.

```
import clr
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Comment: Yes manage to put this but its weird that i can use the abspath, he can detect it but. it doesnt work for no apparent reason. still searching the reason.

Answer (score 0):

A relative path is always relative to the current working directory of the script that is executing. So, that's not (or at least not always) relative to the file the reference is in.

You can set the current working directory in the run configuration in PyCharm. But for your script to work everywhere, you should ensure the current working directory is what you expect it to be for the script and check your paths are relative to that.

Useful commands are `os.getcwd()` and `os.chdir()`.

The default working directory for a script in PyCharm is the directory the script you start itself is in, outside of PyCharm it would be whatever directory you start Python with the script from, or the working directory set in a shortcut.